# Replace HTML with PlaceHolder control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, placeholder

Is there any way to read some HTML and replace that HTML with a PlaceHolder control dynamically at runtime?

For example, I have some HTML that contains tags such as ##MainContent## or ##SideContent##.

I need to somehow find each tag and dynamically add a asp:PlaceHolder control.

EDIT - The reason for this is to read the HTML in and then dynamically add controls to a section of the page. I'm attempting to create a CMS system, although I'm not sure this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is a thought exercise. :)

Ideally, you should just replace those tags in your markup with an `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control. If you cannot do that (for whatever reason), try replacing them with an `<asp:Literal>` control:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litMainContent" runat="server" Text="##MainContent##"><asp:Literal>
<asp:Literal ID="litSideContent" runat="server" Text="##SideContent##"><asp:Literal>
```

That way, they will still render on the page exactly as they do now. Then you should be able to use `litMainContent` and `litSideContent` in your code-behind:

For VB.Net:

```
Dim phMainContent As PlaceHolder = New PlaceHolder
Dim phMainContent As PlaceHolder = New PlaceHolder

litMainContent.Controls.Add(phMainContent)
litSideContent.Controls.Add(phSideContent)
```

For C#.Net

```
PlaceHolder phMainContent = new PlaceHolder();
PlaceHolder phMainContent = new PlaceHolder();

litMainContent.Controls.Add(phMainContent);
litSideContent.Controls.Add(phSideContent);
```